# Make TextView turn orange when focused?

Tags: android

I have a textview, I set it as clickable and focusable - how do I get it to highlight to orange (like a button) when the user focuses it with the trackwheel etc?:

```
TextView tv = ...;
tv.setClickable(true);
tv.setFocusable(true);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is quite easy. Here is the solution.

You have an TextView element with its background attribute set to `@drawable/tbselector` like this.

```
<TextView android:text="My text" 
    android:id="@+id/tv01"
    android:layout_width="300dip"
    android:layout_height="150dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"  
    android:background="@drawable/tbselector"/>
```

The last attribute `android:background` is essential the other stuff is up to you.

Now you create a `tbselector.xml` in your `drawable` subdirectory. Which looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/bgdefault"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_selected="false"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/bgselected"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_selected="false"/>
</selector>
```

Now you create a `bgdefault.xml` in your `drawable` subdirectory which looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <size
        android:width="200dip"
        android:height="150dip"
        android:color="#00FF00"/>
    <solid
        android:color="#00FF00"/>
</shape>
```

Finally create a `bgselected.xml` in your `drawable` subdirectory which looks like the other one with other color values like this for example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <size
        android:width="200dip"
        android:height="150dip"
        android:color="#FFFF00"/>
    <solid
        android:color="#FFFF00"/>
</shape>
```

And thats it you now have a state dependent TextView background. You can however decide to set your drawables in your selector XML it's totally up to you. My values are just random values to show you the difference.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am going to deflate 200 textviews while loading. seems to much of processing. is it fine? or i should do it at touch/Focus listener?

Comment: I can't really tell to be honest. I guess it's not going to be more to process than doing it the programmatic way. If you'd like to try it (given that you have the time to) and get back to me with the results it#d be great.

Comment: this question is old, but is there a way to access the android default focused-background-color?

Answer (score 0):

I have no chance to try it at the moment, but what about adding a `OnFocusChangeListener` to your `TextView` and then use the `setBackgroundColor(int color)` method to change the background to orange