# change textview color on focus

Tags: android, textview

I have imageview, textview and other views inside my relative layout. Now my problem is textview color is not getting changed when it is focused. My layout is

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/view"
 android:background="@drawable/bg1"
 android:focusable="true"
 android:clickable="true" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
 <TextView 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/text" 
android:textStyle="bold" 
android:textSize="20dp"
 android:textColor="@color/selector" />
```

i referred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360297/textview-color-change-on-focus-press) and added `android:duplicateParentState="true"` on my textview  but this solution is also not working for me.. help me in resolving this issue.. Thanks in advance..

EDIT: If i use android:background am getting an error and my logcat is

```
    11-12 08:39:20.916: E/AndroidRuntime(4691): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-12 08:39:20.916: E/AndroidRuntime(4691): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myview.myapp/com.myview.myapp.Mainclass}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class <unknown>
11-12 08:39:20.916: E/AndroidRuntime(4691):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
11-12 08:39:20.916: E/AndroidRuntime(4691):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
11-12 08:39:20.916: E/AndroidRuntime(4691):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
11-12 08:39:20.916: E/AndroidRuntime(4691):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
11-12 08:39:20.916: E/AndroidRuntime(4691):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-12 08:39:20.916: E/AndroidRuntime(4691):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-12 08:39:20.916: E/AndroidRuntime(4691):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4429)
11-12 08:39:20.916: E/AndroidRuntime(4691):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 08:39:20.916: E/AndroidRuntime(4691):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-12 08:39:20.916: E/AndroidRuntime(4691):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
11-12 08:39:20.916: E/AndroidRuntime(4691):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
11-12 08:39:20.916: E/AndroidRuntime(4691):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-12 08:39:20.916: E/AndroidRuntime(4691): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

Here line 43 is starting of textview in xml

Answer (score 1):

HI i just tried the below way and it worked for me

Create a drawable file colorchange.xml as below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/holo_red_light" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:color="@android:color/white" /> 
</selector>
```

and then add the xml to the textcolor of the textview,

```
android:textColor="@drawable/colorchange"
```

hope this helps.

Comment: What is the logic of using double states?

Answer (score 0):

Implement OnFocusChangeListener for your TextView

```
textView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus){
        //do something
    }else {
       //do something 
    }
   }
});
```

Comment: You can do the same with design itself i.e. by using xml. Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678472/

Comment: i need to achieve this in xml, can it possible

Answer (score 0):

Implement XML Drawable. You can implement effect onFocus, onPress etc by defining it in xml.
mycustom.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/your_imagename_while_focused"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/your_imagename_while_pressed" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image_name_while_notpressed" />  //means normal
</selector>
```

Android in textView xml.

```
<TextView
.
.
.
.
android:Background="@drawable/mycustom.xml"
.
/>
```

Comment: it is throwing view inflate exception neat textview. I tried this also